# Product types (movie, Book) have different fields, where best to store these in database?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel Eloquent. I have a products table with fields such as title, description, price, and product_type_id as each product belongsTo a type, so a product type could be 'Book' or 'Movie'. A Product can only belongTo one type.

Now both Book and Movie products require storing different properites about each, for a Book i would need to store 'author', 'num_of_pages' etc and for Movie i would need to store 'director', 'runtime' etc.

These are not dynamic properties, they are fixed for each type so there not custom fields.

I could store all these 'properties' as columns on the products table but that would mean a ton of null fields. I would ideally like to store them in their respective properties table, so book_product_properties and movie_product_properties. So it would be a one-to-one between products and movie_product_properties OR books_product_properties.

How do I model the relationships in Eloquent between products and many different properties tables?

I need to able to easily query for all products and get there properties.

I tried an EAV approach, storing properties in a key/value table but I been reading up on EAV and most posts say to stay away from it, as its very slow to query and a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Table:

```
Products
   id - integer
   type - varchar
   additional_data - json
```

Migration:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('type')
    $table->json('additional_data')
});
```

Model:

```
class Product extends Model
{ 
   $casts = [
      'additional_data' => 'array'
   ];
}
```

**Solution 2:**

You can use One To Many (Polymorphic) https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Your tables will looks like:

```
Books
    id - integer
    title - string
 
Movies
    id - integer
    title - string
 
Products
    id - integer
    productable_id - integer
    productable_type - string
```

Migration:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->id();
     $table->morphs('productable') // this will create 2 fields: productable_id and productable_type;
       //....
});
```

In your models:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the parent productable model (book or movie).
     */
    public function productable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;
 
class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the book's products.
     */
    public function products(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Product::class, 'productable');
    }
}
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;
 
class Movie extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the movie's products.
     */
    public function products(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Product::class, 'productable');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Khan. I did think doing polymorphic associations, only issue I see is when deleting a product I would have to set up an event listener to delete the respective property row also as there is no FK constraint. I would also be repeating many common fields across many tables, like title in your example. I could place all common fields to all products on the products table though.

Comment: Yeah, for common fields, you could put then in products table and for different fields, you put them in movies or books table

Comment: I added one more solution to my answer. Hope it's useful

Comment: if I have a product type that didnt require additional fields, let say its a very simple product such as an umbrella but it still needs a type so lets call its type 'simple_product', I would then need to make productable_id and productable_type nullable, since umbrella requires no properties. I still need to store its type though. So products table could be id, product_type_id, title, property_id (nullable, could be book or movie id), property_type (nullable, could be App/Models/BookProperty or App/Models/MovieProperty) Is this ok you think? I changed productable to property_*

Comment: re: json. I did think of using json, I read a blog post recently, see end of comment. They compared eav vs json vs all cols on one table. eav was slowest (very slow), but querying data in json vs all on one table wasn't that much in time difference, JSON approach was only 10-30% slower than the approach of regular columns. https://laraveldaily.com/post/laravel-custom-fields-json-eav-model-same-table

Comment: wouldnt the polymorphic association be one-to-one? As one book product has one row in books table?

Comment: Json is just a problem if you filter the results based on json field. You can use morphOne instead of morphMany

Comment: yeah I would need to filter products based on property, so if the product property is in json, that's a problem. If a user is looking at books i would like for them to filter based on author as an example.

Comment: data is cheap....